# In ng show can we use if condition

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

My requirement is have to allow only the globals.currentUser.syllabus_id==3 to access the developement portfolio, if syllabus match then have to check for the mentioned role, if both syllabus and role match only the menu developement portfolio to be show other wise it should not show the menu.

```
<li
     ng-show="globals.currentUser.roleid==1 ||globals.currentUser.roleid==2 || globals.currentUser.roleid==4 || globals.currentUser.roleid==5 || globals.currentUser.roleid==10 || globals.currentUser.roleid==11">
 <a href=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Development portfolio </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#!), it has all information. Maybe you want to use a function expression or a filter instead of doing this complex logic inline.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, write a function which does this check and returns a boolean and call that function from markup.

in controller

`vm.isUserEligibleToSeeSomething = function() { return false; // true }`

in markup

`<li ng-show="vm.isUserEligibleToSeeSomething()"></li>`

Comment: This solution is better than writing complex logic inline, but the function will be evaluated on every change detection cycle. To prevent this, a filter should be used instead.

Comment: @JSONDerulo I didn't know you can use a filter inside an `ng-show`. Do you have an example?

Comment: @JacobStamm As per [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#!), the string inside ng-show is interpreted as expression. [Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#!) can be applied to any expression. So I don't see a limitation why you shouldn't be able to write a custom filter returning a boolean, which will be passed to ng-show to show/hide the element